# Potentially multiple instances of hardhat is running without me wanting

Tags: hardhat

I am starting hardhat and successfully deploying a series of contracts to my local hardhat instance. However when I try to call them via TS script I am getting below log in the hardhat log. The address is correct. Actually, I was using the same TS file and the same address exactly same way previously and instead of this message I was getting expected logs from events. In the same window, previously I was seeing logs realted to deployments etc. Now, only this message. When I check the windows task I see multiple instances of node running instead of 2 (one for chain and one for the TS. I am killing all of them and restarting everything, immediately I am seeing many instances of node in the tasks. Which is not a problem but maybe an indicator or multiple hardhat instances running I guess. Because although I deploy successfully, I do not see the logs for deployment or logs which would be related to the actions of deployed contract which was not the case before. I am not sure what caused this problem. Please help me to solve this.
Many thanks in advance..
Ferda

```
WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contract
  From: address
  To:   address
```